# Meteor / Blaze rendering : {{each}} in another {{each}} doesn't return the right data (data context)

Tags: templates, meteor, meteor-blaze, helper

I was wondering if you could give me some clue how to tackle this 'problem'. I'm a newbie in JS (+ Meteor), so it might be super simple for you. I'm working with `helpers` and `blaze/spacebars` for rendering.

I have a simple helper:

```
Template.monitoring.helpers({

    'realtime': function(){
        return {
            house:    house.find( {} ),
            neighbours: neighbours.find( {} ),
        }
    } // end of realtime

}); // end of helpers
```

At this point, everything is OK. I'm able to retrieve the data I want. The problem is that I'm not able to render it like I want. Below my `template`.

```
<template name="monitoring">

   {{#each realtime.house}}
   <div class="card red">
     SHOW STUFF ABOUT HOUSE
   </div>

    <div class="card blue">
        {{#each realtime.neighbours}}
        SHOW STUFF ABOUT NEIGHBOURS OF THE SPECIFIC HOUSE
        {{/each}}
  </div>

  {{/each}} -> end of each realtime.house

</template>
```

More precisely, when my template is rendered:

- number of red cards = number of houses => perfect
- each red card contains the data of **one** house => perfect
- number of blue cards = number of houses => perfect
- each blue card contains the data of **all neighbours** => WRONG. What I want is the data of neighbours concerning the specific house

Do you have how to get the right stuff at the right place?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two helpers: one which returns the houses, and one which returns the neighbors with a house as its context. Without the schema, I can't give a precise answer but let's assume each neighbor has a `houseId` property which joins the two.

```js
Template.monitoring.helpers({
  houses: function () {
    return house.find();
  },

  neighbors: function () {
    // Note the context here is a house because it's
    // called from within an each.
    return neighbours.find({ houseId: this._id });
  },
});
```

And your template would look something like this (assuming neighbors should each be in a blue card):

```html
<template name="monitoring">
  {{#each houses}}
    <div class="card red">
      SHOW STUFF ABOUT HOUSE
    </div>
    {{#each neighbours}}
      <div class="card blue">
        SHOW STUFF ABOUT NEIGHBOURS OF THE SPECIFIC HOUSE
      </div>
    {{/each}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```