# Misunderstanding `each...in` rendering with reactive variable

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars

I'm new to **Meteor/Blaze** but that is what my company is using.

I'm struggling to understand how Blaze decides to render what based on `ReactiveDict`

### TL;DR

I create some children templates from a `ReactiveDict` array in the parent array. The data is not refreshed in the children templates when the `ReactiveDict` changes and I don't understand why.

I probably have misunderstood something about Blaze rendering. Could you help me out?

---

### Parent

#### Parent Html template

```html
<template name="parent">
    {{#each child in getChildren}}
        {{> childTemplate (childArgs child)}}
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

#### Parent Javascript

Reactive variable

The template renders children templates from a `getChildren` helper that just retrieves a `ReactiveDict`.

```js
// Child data object
const child = () => ({
  id: uuid.v4(),
  value: ""
});

// Create a reactive dictionary
Template.parent.onCreated(function() {
  this.state = new ReactiveDict();
  this.state.setDefault({ children: [child()] });
});
```

```js
// Return the children from the reactive dictionary
Template.parent.helpers({
  getChildren() {
    return Template.instance().state.get('children');
  }
});
```

Child template arguments (from **parent** template)

The parent template gives the child template some data used to set default values and callbacks.
Each is instantiated using a `childArgs` function that uses the child's `id` to set the correct data and callbacks.
When clicking a `add` button, it adds a child to the `children` array in the `ReactiveDict`.
When clicking a `delete` button, it removes the child from the `children` array in the `ReactiveDict`.

```js
Template.parent.helpers({
    // Set the children arguments: default values and callbacks
    childArgs(child) {
        const instance = Template.instance();
        const state = instance.state;
        const children = state.get('children');
        return {
           id: child.id,
           // Default values
           value: child.value, 
           // Just adding a child to the reactive variable using callback
           onAddClick() {
                const newChildren = [...children, child()];
                state.set('children', newChildren); 
           },
           // Just deleting the child in the reactive variable in the callback
           onDeleteClick(childId) { 
                const childIndex = children.findIndex(child => child.id === childId);
                children.splice(childIndex, 1);
                state.set('children', children); 
            }
        }
    }
})
```

### Child

#### Child html template

The template displays the data from the parent and 2 buttons, `add` and `delete`.

```html
<template name="child">
        <div>{{value}}</div>
        <button class="add_row" type="button">add</button>
        <button class="delete_row" type="button">delete</button>
</template>
```

#### Child javascript (events)

The two functions called here are the callbacks passed as arguments from the **parent** template.

```js
// The two functions are callbacks passed as parameters to the child template
Template.child.events({
  'click .add_row'(event, templateInstance) {
    templateInstance.data.onAddClick();
  },
  'click .delete_row'(event, templateInstance) {
    templateInstance.data.onDeleteClick(templateInstance.data.id);
  },
```

---

### Problem

My problem is that when I delete a child (using a callback to set the `ReactiveDict` like the `onAddClick()` function), my data is not rendered correctly.

#### Text Example:

I add rows like this.

```
child 1 | value 1
child 2 | value 2
child 3 | value 3
```

When I delete the `child 2`, I get this:

```
child 1 | value 1
child 3 | value 2
```

And I want this:

```
child 1 | value 1
child 3 | value 3
```

I'm initialising the `child` with the data from `childArgs` in the `Template.child.onRendered()` function.

1. **Good**: The `getChildren()` function is called when deleting the `child` in the `ReactiveDict` and I have the correct data in the variable (`children` in the `ReactiveDict`).
2. **Good**: If I have 3 children and I delete one, the **parent** template renders only 2 children.
3. **Bad**: Yet the child's `onRendered()` is never called (neither is the child's `onCreated()` function). Which means the data displayed for the **child** template is wrong.

#### Picture example

I am adding pictures to help understand:

Correct html

The displayed HTML is correct: I had 3 children, and I deleted the second one. In my HTML, I can see that the two children that are displayed have the correct ID in their divs. Yet the displayed data is wrong.

[image: correct html]

Stale data

I already deleted the second child in the first picture. The children displayed should be the first and the third. 
In the console log, my data is correct. Red data is the first. Purple is the third.

Yet we can see that the deleted child's data is displayed (`asd` and `asdasd`). When deleting a tag, I can see the second child's ID in the log, though it should not exist anymore. The second child ID is in green.

[image: stale data]

I probably have misunderstood something. Could you help me out?

Comment: This question is incomplete in order to be answered. We basically also need the html part of `parent` and if there is a `child` template also it's html and js code. I am really curious how you invoke the `onDeleteClick` because usually Template events is what should be used for ui events.

Comment: @Jankapunkt This should be all the information needed. Don't hesitate to ask if you feel something else is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem. But I still don't understand how Blaze chooses to render.
Now, the solution looks a bit like the one given by **@Jankapunkt** in the first part of his solution, but not exactly. The `find` to get the child was working completely fine. But now that I make the template rendering dependent on a reactive helper, it re-renders the template when the id changes (which it did not when it was only dependent on the child itself from the `each...in` loop).

In the end, I don't understand what the `each...in` loop does and how it uses the data to loop. See **Caveats**.

To give credits where it's due, I had the idea of implementing that dependency from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37509905/meteor-blaze-rendering-each-in-another-each-doesnt-return-the-right).

## Edits from the original code

I edit the parent template to make the child rendering dependent on its own id. That way, when the `child.id` changes, the template re-renders.

### Html template

I added a dependency on the `child.id` to re-render the child template.

```html
<template name="parent">
    {{#each childId in getChildrenIds}}
        {{#let child=(getChild childId)}}
            {{> childTemplate (childArgs child)}}
        {{/let}}
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

### Javascript

I have now two helpers. One to return the ids for the `each...in` loop, the other to return the child from the id and force the child template re-render.

```js
Template.parent.helpers({
    // Return the children ids from the reactive dictionary
    getChildrenIds() {
        const children = Template.instance().state.get('children');
        const childrenIds = children.map(child => child.id);
        return childrenIds;
    },
    // Return the child object from its id
    getChild(childId) {
        const children = Template.instance().state.get('children');
        const child = children.find(child => child.id === childId);
        return child;
    }
});
```

## Complete Code

Here is the complete solution.

### Parent

#### Html template

```html
<template name="parent">
    {{#each childId in getChildrenIds}}
        {{#let child=(getChild childId)}}
            {{> childTemplate (childArgs child)}}
        {{/let}}
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

#### Javascript

```js
// Child data object
const child = () => ({
  id: uuid.v4(),
  value: ""
});

// Create a reactive dictionary
Template.parent.onCreated(function() {
  this.state = new ReactiveDict();
  this.state.setDefault({ children: [child()] });
});

Template.parent.helpers({
    // Return the children ids from the reactive dictionary
    getChildrenIds() {
        const children = Template.instance().state.get('children');
        const childrenIds = children.map(child => child.id);
        return childrenIds;
    },
    // Return the child object from its id
    getChild(childId) {
        const children = Template.instance().state.get('children');
        const child = children.find(child => child.id === childId);
        return child;
    },
    // Set the children arguments: default values and callbacks
    childArgs(child) {
        const instance = Template.instance();
        const state = instance.state;
        const children = state.get('children');
        return {
           id: child.id,
           // Default values
           value: child.value, 
           // Just adding a child to the reactive variable using callback
           onAddClick() {
                const newChildren = [...children, child()];
                state.set('children', newChildren); 
           },
           // Just deleting the child in the reactive variable in the callback
           onDeleteClick(childId) { 
                const childIndex = children.findIndex(child => child.id === childId);
                children.splice(childIndex, 1);
                state.set('children', children); 
            }
        }
    }
});
```

### Child

#### Html template

```html
<template name="child">
    <div>{{value}}</div>
    <button class="add_row" type="button">add</button>
    <button class="delete_row" type="button">delete</button>
</template>
```

#### Javascript

```js
Template.child.events({
    'click .add_row'(event, templateInstance) {
        templateInstance.data.onAddClick();
    },
    'click .delete_row'(event, templateInstance) {
        templateInstance.data.onDeleteClick(templateInstance.data.id);
    }
});
```

## Caveats

The solution is working. But my `each..in` loop is weird.

When I delete a child, I get the correct IDs when the `getChildrenIds()` helper is called.

But the `each..in` loops over the original IDs, even those who were deleted and are **NOT** in the `getChildrenIds()` return value. The template is not rendered of course because the `getChild(childId)` throws an error (the child is deleted). The display is then correct.

I don't understand that behaviour at all. Anybody knows what is happening here?

If anybody has the definitive answer, I would love to hear it.

Comment: `getChildrenIds()` appears not to be a _reactive_ helper. That means it's not automatically getting refreshed when the state changes, thus it returns a stale list. Not sure why your template state isn't reactive, it should be. Why are you managing the state by hand instead of just letting Meteor manage it?

Comment: Hello! I'm sorry but I don't understand your question. What do you mean by "letting Meteor manage it"? How would Meteor manage my state for me? I'm creating children and need an id because they hold data and I would like to keep the correct user input when deleting an input row at any index, and Meteor/Blaze doesn't refresh the template by itself. I haven't found a way to do it correctly, that's why I used my solution. If you have a better way of doing this, I'd love to hear it! Thanks for your time.

Comment: Normally the client state in Meteor apps is managed in minimongo and your template helper would simply do a `collectionName.find()` to give you the list of items to be displayed in your template. Deleting an item would result in the template being automatically re-rendered with the deleted element removed. You've added your own state management and for some reason it's not triggering a re-render.

Comment: I don't see how minimongo should be used to manage UI state in the client. I don't even see it recommended anywhere in the docs. Why should I use the publication/subscription mechanics to save UI related data? Why should I call the dB to simply have the item display the proper entered data?

You recommend that I save my data in the client dB just to remember some stuff the user typed in my UI? It seems very hacky to me. I don't mean to seem rude or dismissive, I just don't understand how that would be a sane and correct way to manage UI state. I thought reactive var/dict were here for that.

Comment: Depends on whether your state is pure UI or state that is synchronized to the server.  If the `children` in your code represent database objects then you really want to be using collections with publish & subscribe. If they are pure UI objects with no back end then sure you have other many other options. You can also use minimongo purely on the client side where it can be quite useful, ex: https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/using-meteor-local-collections-to-support-browser-based-cryptography

Comment: It is indeed pure UI, not database objects. Thank you very much for the link, I will look into this!

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure where to start but there are many errors and I rather like to provide a running solution here with comments.

First the `each` function should correctly pass the id instead of the whole child or the `find` will result in faults:

```html
<template name="parent">
  {{#each child in getChildren}}
    {{#with (childArgs child.id)}}
      {{> childTemplate this}}
    {{/with}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

In the helper you can avoid calling too many of the `Template.instance()` functions by using [lexical scoping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures):

```js
childArgs (childId) {
  const instance = Template.instance()
  const children = instance.state.get('children')
  const childData = children.find(child => child.id === childId)
  const value = {
    // Default values
    data: childData,

    // Just adding a child to the reactive variable using callback
    onAddClick () {
      const children = instance.state.get('children')
      const length = children ? children.length : 1
      const newChild = { id: `data ${length}` }
      const newChildren = [...children, newChild]
      instance.state.set('children', newChildren)
    },

    // Just deleting the child in the reactive variable in the callback
    onDeleteClick (childId) {
      const children = instance.state.get('children')
      const childIndex = children.findIndex(child => child.id === childId)
      children.splice(childIndex, 1)
      instance.state.set('children', children)
    }
  }
  return value
}
```

Then note, that in the event callback `'click .delete_row'` you are using `templateInstance.data.id` but this is **always** `undefined` with your current structure. It should be `templateInstance.data.data.id` because `data` is always defined for all data coming in a Template instance and if you name a property `data` then you have to access it via `data.data`:

```js
Template.childTemplate.events({
  'click .add_row' (event, templateInstance) {
    templateInstance.data.onAddClick()
  },
  'click .delete_row' (event, templateInstance) {
    templateInstance.data.onDeleteClick(templateInstance.data.id)
  }
})
```

Now it also makes sense why your data was weirdly sorted. Take a look at the `onDeleteClick` callback:

```
onDeleteClick (childId) {
  // childId is always undefined in your code
  const children = instance.state.get('children')
  const childIndex = children.findIndex(child => child.id === childId)
  // childIndex is always -1 in your code
  // next time make a dead switch in such situations:
  if (childIndex === -1) {
    throw new Error(`Expected child by id ${childId}`)
  }
  children.splice(childIndex, 1)
  // if index is -1 this removes the LAST element
  instance.state.set('children', children)
}
```

So your issue was the splice behavior and passing an unchecked index into splice:

> The index at which to start changing the array. If greater than the length of the array, start will be set to the length of the array. If negative, it will begin that many elements from the end of the array (with origin -1, meaning -n is the index of the nth last element and is therefore equivalent to the index of array.length - n). If array.length + start is less than 0, it will begin from index 0.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: First, thank you a lot for taking the time to check my question.

Concerning the `id`, I'm sorry I forgot to add the part of code where I set it. I added it to the question now.

I do **not** have any problem with the `add`/`delete` functions. Everything is working, my reactive dictionary is always in the right state.
The `getChildren()` helper is called, and the reactive dictionary's value is correct.

The problem is that the correct child is deleted from the reactive dictionary, one child template is deleted, but the remaining child templates are not re-rendered so the data is stale.

Comment: PS: I did not put protection in case of deletion of the last row because they already exist in the production code, and are not relevant to my question. Concerning the instance variable, I've corrected it in the exemple but it is already in my production code, and also not relevant to my problem.

Comment: I don't want to sound rude but could someone explain why this answer keeps getting upvoted when it doesn't answer the problem? If it is for the effort put, I agree it deserves it, especially since I forgot to add the complete code the first time I posted the question. Thank you all! :)

Answer (score 0):

### Correct way of solving this issue

The correct way to fix this is to create your own _id which gets a new unique _id each time the array of objects changes. It is outlined in the Blaze docs here: http://blazejs.org/api/spacebars.html#Reactivity-Model-for-Each

This will only happen when you are dealing with #each blocks with non-cursors, like arrays or arrays of objects.

Cursor-based data together with #each blocks works fine and gets rerendered correctly, like Pages.findOne(id).

### Examples if you need to deal with arrays and #each blocks

**Not working**

```
[
  {
    name: "Fred",
    value: 1337
  },
  {
    name: "Olga",
    value: 7331
  }
]
```

**Working**

```
[
  {
    name: "Fred",
    value: 1337,
    _id: "<random generated string>"
  },
  {
    name: "Olga",
    value: 7331,
    _id: "<random generated string>"
  }
]
```